# What is the meaning of "hold something for more?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> What about The Sun also and the movies? Any chance? I dint put in
> about the good parts. You know how good they are. You’re write about
> the book of stories. I wanted to **hold it for more**. That last one I had
> in Cosmopolitan would have made it.

This is what Ernest Hemingway wrote on the envelope of a [letter](https://www.writerswrite.co.za/writing-advice-from-ernest-hemingway-to-f-scott-fitzgerald/) to F.Scott Fitzgerald.
I wonder what does "hold it for more" mean in this context. Does it mean Ernest wanted to "read more" of Scott's movie script?
(I thought the book of stories refers to movie scripts since Cosmopolitan is screenplay by F. Scott Fitzgerald)

Comment: I'd guess Hemingway was talking about his own collection of stories Winner Take Nothing - saying he had wanted the publishers to wait till there were more to include. It came out a few months before that letter.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm a native speaker and I'm not sure. There's clearly a lot of context missing that Fitzgerald and Hemingway share. Cosmopolitan is also a magazine that would have published stories. My only guess is that Hemingway wanted to hold one of his stories for more money. But that's really just a guess. Either way, it's not an idiomatic English expression.

Comment: I think "That last one I had in Cosmopolitan would have made it" means the short story of his which Cosmopolitan had recently printed could have been included if the publisher had waited.